# SQL 2012 Return count and sum between two times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've asked about this query before, and I made some progress.  Now I'm needing a more restricted data set, but am having problems with my code.  Here's what I'm using:

```
DECLARE @mindate DATETIME = '2011-12-30'
DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME = '2011-12-31'

;WITH cte
 AS (SELECT 
        CONVERT(DATETIME,@mindate) AS [StartDate],
        DATEADD(MI, 10,CONVERT(DATETIME,@mindate)) AS [EndDate]
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 
        DATEADD(MI, 10, [StartDate]),
        DATEADD(MI, 10, [EndDate])
     FROM   cte
     WHERE  [StartDate] < CONVERT(DATETIME,@maxdate))

SELECT 
  [StartDate],
  [EndDate],
  COUNT(cr.MESSAGE_SIZE) AS [TransactionItemsMigrated],
  SUM(cr.MESSAGE_SIZE) AS [TransactionSizeBytes],
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MESSAGE WHERE MESSAGE_STATUS = 2) [CurrentItemsFailed]
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN CROSS_REFERENCE cr
  ON cr.MIGRATION_DATE_TIME BETWEEN [StartDate] AND [EndDate]
GROUP BY cte.StartDate, cte.EndDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I need to show a row every 10 minutes, even if TransactionItemsMigrated and/or TransactionSizeBytes are 0 or NULL.  The results I'm getting are not showing every 10 minutes.  The span between StartDate and EndDate is showing correctly, and it seems that the items and size are counted correctly, but StartDate is jumping by more than 10 minutes.  Each entry below is one row.

```
StartDate 2016-02-01 00:40:00.000
EndDate 2016-02-01 00:50:00.000
TransactionItemsMigrated 1925
TransactionSizeBytes 1843712
CurrentItemsFailed 6538601

StartDate 2016-02-01 01:50:00.000
EndDate 2016-02-01 02:00:00.000
TransactionItemsMigrated 1892
TransactionSizeBytes 51712
CurrentItemsFailed 6538601
```

I can't paste results because it's being run on a VM that I don't have copy/paste access from.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, the example data is just sampled, not my actual results.  Don't worry about the dates, other than seeing that there is a gap between the StartTime's

Comment: Can you add an Order by and check if it is really not showing all the intervals or just unordered?

Comment: Are you intentionally excluding 10 minute intervals on `@maxdate`? Note that `between` uses a [closed interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Terminology) when you probably want `start <= event < end` to avoid double counting events.

Comment: Man, talk about egg on my face.  @mxix I believe you were right.  It looks like some of the results were mixed in.  ORDER BY seems to have fixed it.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you to forget using recursive to achieve your goal since this won't be performing and that you already seem to have problem with it?

For what you are doing, I would go with a [tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/).

Here is a translation of your script using a tally table. This will perform must better and at the same time, it may or may not resolve your issue, but you are bound to know more about the issue if it still there.

```
;WITH
t1      AS (SELECT N = 1  UNION ALL SELECT 1 N), 
t2      AS (SELECT N = 1  FROM t1 x, t1 y),
t3      AS (SELECT N = 1  FROM t2 x, t2 y),
t4      AS (SELECT N = 1  FROM t3 x, t3 y),
t5      AS (SELECT N = 1  FROM t4 x, t4 y),
Tally   AS (SELECT N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
            FROM t5 AS x, t5 as y)--building a tally with recursive but an less expensive one then the one you had.

SET DATEFORMAT YMD
DECLARE @mindate DATETIME = '2011-12-30'
DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME = '2011-12-31'
DECLARE @NMax    INT
SELECT @NMax = ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @mindate, @maxdate) / 10, 0) --Count the number of 10 minutes slice between the two dates.

SELECT  [StartDate]                 = DATEADD(MINUTE, (Tally.N - 1) * 10, @mindate),
        [EndDate]                   = DATEADD(MINUTE, (Tally.N) * 10, @mindate),
        [TransactionItemsMigrated]  = COUNT(cr.MESSAGE_SIZE),
        [TransactionSizeBytes]      = SUM(cr.MESSAGE_SIZE),
        [CurrentItemsFailed]        = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MESSAGE WHERE MESSAGE_STATUS = 2) 
FROM Tally
LEFT JOIN CROSS_REFERENCE AS cr ON DATEADD(MINUTE, (Tally.N - 1) * 10, @mindate) >= cr.MIGRATION_DATE_TIME
                                AND DATEADD(MINUTE, (Tally.N) * 10, @mindate) < cr.MIGRATION_DATE_TIME
WHERE Tally.N <= @NMax
ORDER BY Tally.N
```

Comment: Like @habo commented, I did replace the BETWEEN with a Start <= eventDate < End

Comment: It's good info and I definitely appreciate the contribution.  Plus I really like the way you format your code!  Very nice on the eyes.  However, this one took about 24.5 seconds to run, and the other (now that I have it working!) takes right at 15 seconds.  Not sure what's causing the discrepancy, but I'll go with the other for now.  Thanks again!

Comment: @doc, my bad I just re-read your code and saw that your cte happen to be exactly like a TallyTable. In addition, your tally table built the right date, so it can then be used in the join. Mine has to compute it, so yeah...

Comment: All good!  I actually found out that the results were there, just not ordered.  So adding an ORDER BY clause fixed it.  Ugh...sorry to have wasted your time, buddy.